# "babel-node" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo -- Node v16

Tags: nodejs, babel

He estado varios días luchando con este error sin solución. Empecé un pequeño proyecto para explorar las nuevas características de Nodejs (version 16) pero no puedo configurar babel de ninguna manera. El error es el siguiente:

```
> config-test@1.0.0 start
> nodemon --exec babel-node src/index.js

[nodemon] 2.0.12
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `babel-node src/index.js`
"babel-node" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

El proyecto de prueba es sumamente sencillo.
Estructura:

```
--src
  -index.js
-- package.json
-- .babelrc
```

**index.js**

```
console.log("hello world");
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "config-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.14.8",
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/node": "^7.14.9",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

He intentado instalar `@babel/cli` a nivel global pero sin exito. También intente usando `babel-cli` pero tampoco funcionó. Claro, con cualquier cambio en el package.json elimino la carpeta `node_modules` par asegurarme de instalar bien todas las dependencias.

Tengo `nvm` instalado y puedo cambiar fácilmente entre las versiones *v14.17.5* y *16.6.2*.
Con node v14 las cosas funcionan bien!
¿Alguno ha podido hacer funcionar babel con Node v16+?

Comment: Si el objetivo es simplemente hacer funcionar babel usando node V16 tal vez te sirva este articulo donde explica [cómo configurar babel](https://www.dalerun.com/instalacion-minima-de-babel-7). Me parece que en lugar de ejecutar el paquete directamente con "nodemon --exec babel-node src/index.js" podrías usar npx como en el artículo: "nodemon --exec npx babel src/index.js". Tampoco parece que sea necesario usar nodemon para tu prueba aunque si también quieres probar eso tal vez quieras hacer primero una cosa simple y luego añadir mas elementos a tu prueba.

Comment: Gracias! Al parecer las configuraciones de babel fueron evolucionando de lo que usaba a diario. El problema parece que era por npm. Puedo confirmar que con npm v7.20.3, añadiendo `npx` al comando y con varias limpiezas de cache y node_modules... pudo funcionar al fin! :)
Si, el ejemplo adjunto era el minimo necesario para fallar, mi proyecto en si es mucho mayor

Answer (score 6):

Cambia la sección de scripts en la configuración json por:

```
"scripts": {
    "babel-node": "babel-node --presets=@babel/preset-env",
    "dev": "nodemon --exec npm run babel-node src/index.js"
}
```

Comment: Estamos en SOes y por ello, todas las preguntas, respuestas y comentarios deben ir en español. Puedes traducir tu respuesta, por favor?

Comment: Listo, gracias por la observación

Answer (score 3):

Hola en mi caso cuyo error fue el mismo,
Lo pude solucionar con esto...

```sh
npm i -g  @babel/node
```

Comment: a mi me ha bastado con `npm i @babel/node` , no es necesario hacer la instalación global.

Answer (score 1):

en mi caso funciono agrefar pnx al comando start, de la siguiente manera:

```
"start": "nodemon --exec npx babel-node src/index.js"
```

Comment: También uso nvim ...y  funciona.  ¿Aunque no sé que hace npx?

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo solucione de esta manera

```
"dev": "nodemon  --exec npx babel-node src/app.js"
```

Y la configuración de babel a si

```
{

"presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env"
]
```

}